# Error in VB.NET code: "Argument not specified for parameter"

Tags: .net, vb.net, error-handling

When I place `Set_Symbol()` in my code it give me two errors.

Errors:

> Argument not specified for parameter 'e' of 'Private Sub Set_Symbol(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)'.    d:\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Math Game\Math Game\frmindex.vb
>
> Argument not specified for parameter 'sender' of 'Private Sub Set_Symbol(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)'.   d:\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Math Game\Math Game\frmindex.vb

This is what Set_Symbol is:

```
Private Sub Set_Symbol(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles rbnaddition.Click, rbnsubtraction.Click, rbnmultiplication.Click, rbndivision.Click
        Dim rbn As RadioButton
        rbn = CType(sender, RadioButton)
        symbol = rbn.Tag
    End Sub
```

This is how I called it:

```
Private Sub frmindex_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    symbolrbn(0) = rbnaddition
    symbolrbn(1) = rbnsubtraction
    symbolrbn(2) = rbnmultiplication
    symbolrbn(3) = rbndivision
    Set_Symbol()
    Populate()
End Sub
```

Why is it throwing this error?

Comment: Do you actually call it manually? Can you show us the code you placed it in?

Comment: Notice the `Sub` definition requires two parameters `sender` and `e` and you have not supplied it with any during `Load`.

Answer (score 2):

`Set_Symbol()` in `frmindex_Load` won't compile because the method takes two parameters but you are trying to call it without parameters.

You shouldn't mix event-handler code with code that is manually called because they are two different things. If you need to call a method from an event-handler as well as manually from somewhere else, you should provide a method that takes the appropriate parameters(or none if not needed) and call that from both locations.

If you actually wanted to set the `Tag` for each RadioButton, you should provide a method that takes no parameter and sets the Tag property for each RadioButton.

I assuming that the handler should  read the Tag instead of set it.

Comment: ... and from the looks of it, the manual call isn't necessary at all in the `frmindex_Load()` method since it's an event handler for a bunch of other things.

Comment: In fact, no exception is thrown, this is misleading. Rather, the compiler complains.

Comment: @Konrad: adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `Set_Symbol(sender,e)` to make it compile

Comment: But what for? The `(sender, e)` of the form's Load event seem irrelevant to the `Set_Symbol` handler.

Comment: If you're calling directly an event handler you should set the same parameters and event handler will do. You really should call Set_Symbol(rbnaddition,EventArgs.Empty) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the `Sub` definition requires two parameters `sender` and `e` and you have not supplied it with any during `Load`. Luckily you already have a `sender` and `e` defined, if you chain the event. So you could directly handle the `Load` event like the radiobutton actions, or call it with the two parameters.

```
Private Sub Set_Symbol(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles rbnaddition.Click, rbnsubtraction.Click, rbnmultiplication.Click, _
rbndivision.Click, MyBase.Load
    Dim rbn As RadioButton
    rbn = CType(sender, RadioButton)
    If rbn IsNot Nothing then
        symbol = rbn.Tag
    End If
End Sub
```

**or**

```
Private Sub frmindex_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Handles MyBase.Load
    symbolrbn(0) = rbnaddition
    symbolrbn(1) = rbnsubtraction
    symbolrbn(2) = rbnmultiplication
    symbolrbn(3) = rbndivision
    Set_Symbol(rbnaddition, Nothing)            'Default to '+' symbol
    Populate()
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    'Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=admin-pc\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=employee;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim con As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=admin-pc\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=employee;Integrated Security=True")
        con.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into emp_table values('" &TextBox1.Text "')",con)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```